# Draw nodes in e.g. a Chord ring

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a set of nodes that I would like to put into a ring. They all have a numeric property which I would like to use a reference when putting into a ring.

E.g, node with param 32 comes after node with para 22.

What I really need is a library (or something like that) which can make it possible to have the correct "distance" between the nodes, e.g: between 22 and 32 is 10 "units", and between 32 and 35 is 3 "units" where "units" may be an empty numeric slot.

Comment: Thats not really clear. Can you give an example of the ring content after each operation ? < 22 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? 32 ? ? 35 >.

Comment: Well, if we look at the Chord ring, all the examples are drawn with nodes with length equally away from each other: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Chord_network.png. In my setup, these nodes are not positioned at same distance between, hence the 22, 32, 35. Further nodes could be 40, 41, 42, 46, 50, 55, 01, 10, 12, 15 and 17.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a sorted list where the end links to the start. I know of no standard implementation, but it would be pretty easy to implement one yourself.

Something like a doubly linked list with the head and tail connected would work. Add operations would have to traverse the list to find the appropriate position to insert into, making insert an O(n) operation. This would make your list perform realtivly poorly, with pretty much *all* standard list operations being O(n).

You could implement a `distanceToNext` and/or `distanceToPrevious` pretty easily by just getting the values of the current and next/previous nodes and returning the difference.

Edit:
Just realised from the question title that you are probably looking for some GUI library to draw these and I just hinted at the model you might use. I'll have a think about the GUI.

Edit 2:
Your problem boils down to how do you draw a polygon when you only know the length of the sides. I [asked on the maths stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21166/general-rule-algorithm-for-finding-the-points-of-a-polygon-given-only-the-length) for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking time, yes, the running code is there, I need to visualize these nodes in a ring, GUI.

Comment: Thanks, but seems like we got no luck there.